# SQLite query execution takes horrible time for INNER JOIN SELECT Statements

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, performance, sqlite

SQlite query taking too much time to execute table join query like below:

```
SELECT COUNT(Level.ControlStatus) FROM Inspections,Level,RoomData WHERE Level.LevelType = 14 AND ((Level.ID = RoomData.ID or Level.ID = RoomData.ExtraLevelID) AND Level.IsExtraLevel=RoomData.UseExtraLevel AND Level.InspectionUniqueID=RoomData.InspectionUniqueID) AND (Level.SampleRound = Inspections.CurrentSampleRound AND Level.InspectionUniqueID=Inspections.InspectionUniqueID) AND Level.InspectionUniqueID in ('Insp147#355463543462364HUGE')
```

How i can improve the performance as i have many queries in app like this which makes worst performance ever.

Thanks

Comment: What indexes do you have?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson 
sqlite_autoindex_InspectionInfo_1, 
sqlite_autoindex_RoomDataAdditionalRequirements_1,
sqlite_autoindex_RoomDataHygienic_1,
sqlite_autoindex_RoomRejectDataHygienic_1,
sqlite_autoindex_RoomRejectData_1

Comment: Show the database schema and the output of EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN.

Answer (score 0):

Use EXPLAIN to see what indices are used, and which may be missing. If you're sure you have all indices created correctly, it's time to update SQLite. The query planner has been replaced and improved quite a lot in recent versions. Compiling Sqlite for iOS is straight forward (two files required, then just remove the sqlite .dylib of the system from the build settings).